# MFC differences between VS008 and VS0210

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mfc

I need some information about the differences of MFC between VS2008 and VS2010. For example I found some differences in OpenDocumentFile method (docmgr.cpp). Someone knows where can I find this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MSDN page - Breaking Changes in Visual C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for VS2010:

[image: MFC changes]

Comment: Thank you very much! this is the information that I was looking for.